# How to make sure in RTOS that Task1 finish then Task2 start (we don't know scheduling algorithm )?

Tags: c, multithreading, rtos

Below questions many times asked me in multiple interview and every time i confused to give answer properly.

**Suppose RTOS running in single processor system. There are two tasks in that. Task1 print the data like "Up" and Task2 print data like "Down". How do you make sure that Task1 print first then Task2? So output is like below**

Up
Down
Up 
Down
.....

I have suggested the mechanism using global variable like initially global variable have value 1. Ex. `int globaleVar = 1;` Now two task written like below

**Task1**

```
while(1)
{
    if(globaleVar == 1)
    {
        printf("Up");
        globaleVar = 2;
    }

}
```

**Task2**

```
while(1)
{
    if(globaleVar == 2)
    {
        printf("Down");
        globaleVar = 1;
    }

}
```

But they said like what if Task2 get chance before the variable updated from Task1? Why not try using semaphor?

So i am not aware about how it possible using semaphor? Anyone have idea?

Comment: Your solution basically does not use the benefits of a RTOS. a RTOS provides mechanisms like RTOS, IPC, exactly for this kind of question.

Comment: Also, in an interview, you could mention that a RTOS scheduler is not necessraily preemptive but can be cooperative: in that case (to simplify) a task executes forever until it yields.

Comment: Be aware that for many combinations of compiler, platform, and RTOS (and assuming the variable is declared `volatile`), your solution will work fine (albeit with a lot of busy-waiting).  Obviously the interviewers are interested in your understanding of RTOS concepts, but that doesn't mean your solution is invalid.

Comment: Similar problem to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156686/how-to-sync-thread-using-mutex-in-freertos/61237586#61237586) - apart from that the present code does not use synchronisation at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A natural way to do this in an RTOS environment is with two binary semaphores, one for each task.  In pseudocode:

```
BinarySempahore up, dn;

void task_up(void) {
  while (1) {
    wait(up);
    printf("UP ");
    signal(dn);
  }
}

void task_dn(void) {
  while (1) {
    wait(dn);
    printf("DOWN ");
    signal(up);
  }
}

void main(void) {
  dn = create_binary_sempahore(0);
  up = create_binary_semaphore(1);
  start_task(task_dn);
  start_task(task_up);
}
```

Initially task `dn` blocks in `wait` because its semaphore has value zero, but `up` runs, prints its message, wakes up `dn`, then blocks on its own semaphore, which is now zero. Task `dn` is now unblocked from `wait` so prints its message, wakes `up`, then blocks on *its* sempahore, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

For FreeRTOS you can use mutexes [Mutexes](https://www.freertos.org/Real-time-embedded-RTOS-mutexes.html)
or 
[Event groups](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Event-Groups.html)