# How to sync thread using mutex in freeRTOS?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, freertos

I have a code written in freeRTOS, I have to achieve mutex synchronisation so that concurrency doesn't occur, but I have been facing one issue:

```
xSemaphoreHandle xMutex=NULL;

void fn_test1()
{
    int i=0;
    while(1)
    {

        xSemaphoreTake(xMutex,portMAX_DELAY );
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Task1 output = %d", i++);
        xSemaphoreGive(xMutex);
        vTaskDelay(10);
    }
}   
void fn_test2()
{
    int i=0;
    while(1)
    {
        xSemaphoreTake(xMutex,portMAX_DELAY );
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Task2 output = %d", i++);
        xSemaphoreGive(xMutex);
        vTaskDelay(10);
    }
}   

void app_main()
{
    char task_name[16];
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( nvs_flash_init() );
    // initialise_wifi();
    // wait_for_ip();
    xMutex=xSemaphoreCreateMutex();  //xMutex will be storing NULL when Mutex not created
    if(xMutex!=NULL) {
        xTaskCreate(fn_test1,"task1",4096,NULL,1,NULL);
        xTaskCreate(fn_test2,"task2",4096,NULL,1,NULL);
        //vTaskStartScheduler();
    }
}
```

the problem with the code is i am getting output

```
[0;32mI (40) example: Task1 output = 0[0m
[0;32mI (50) example: Task2 output = 0[0m
[0;32mI (547) example: Task2 output = 1[0m
[0;32mI (547) example: Task1 output = 1[0m
[0;32mI (647) example: Task2 output = 2[0m
[0;32mI (647) example: Task1 output = 2[0m
```

-->

> ```
> [0;32mI (747) example: Task1 output = 3[0m
> [0;32mI (747) example: Task2 output = 3[0m
> [0;32mI (847) example: Task2 output = 4[0m
> [0;32mI (847) example: Task1 output = 4[0m
> [0;32mI (947) example: Task1 output = 5[0m
> ```

<--

As you can see task1 is executed twice and after that task2 is executed twice, which is not the ideal output I expect, the ideal output should be alternating between task1 and task2.

I found one article that achieves such a behaviour, [link](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/freertos/mutexes/), but it suggests to tinker with freeRTOS kernel.
I seek an alternate solution. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these two tasks have equal priority, it is acceptable behaviour that they wait for each other for up to a systick period (because they will only be scheduled in the systick!) - this is not a bug, but a feature!

Acquiring the mutex, doing the action (output call in your example code) and returning the mutex apparently takes much less than a systick period (at least, with your present (zero?) load by other tasks/ISRs.

Therefore, we should consider why you want them to be exactly alternating.
If you only want access periods to the shared resource to be scheduled "equally", it might be worth to investigate whether it would also be sufficient if they have an equal number of mutex assignments during a certain, longer period (i.e., fifty-fifty sharing, but not an alternating assignment). If, conversely, there *is* a requirement why task2 must be processed after (and before) task2 (for some reason that comes from your application), it might be a better plan to implement a "token-like" design, where each task triggers the other one explicitly (e. g., using one event per direction, but omitting the current mutex). This design would also behave stable if you create some additional system load around the pair of tasks - while the present mutex+delay design will require readjustment every time the load situation around your two tasks changes.

Answer (score 0):

What if omitting the delay (after releasing the mutex) ? I guess you’ll see the desired toggling behavior.
I could imagine that while e.g. task1 is still sleeping after releasing the mutex task2 finishes it’s output quickly enough (within 1 tick period) and also fells asleep. So the delay expires for both tasks at the same time or tick. Given both tasks have the same prio the scheduler is absolutely free to make either task running.